# Boolean operator across an entire list (Python)

Tags: python, list, boolean

I'm trying something quite simple but not managing to get the result I'm expecting.

I have a list of strings and would like to perform a comparison across the entire list in a single expression, without resorting to a for loop.

e.g.

```
>>> str = ['P','R','R']   
>>> [str == 'P' for i in str]   
[False, False, False]
```

Obviously I'm looking for `[True, False, False]` in this situation, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have used a keyword `str` as a variable. Change that to something else

Comment: You want to test against `i` instead...

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to change 
`prism_bool = [str == 'P' for i in str]` to

`prism_bool = [i == 'P' for i in str]`